# Magento 2.4.6 + Braintree: How to stop placing order when tranasaction is failed

Tags: magento2, checkout, braintree

Magento: 2.4.6

Braintree: 4.5.0

When a braintree transaction failed with a reason like 'Processor Declined' or 'Gateway Rejected', Magento also created an order with 'Canceled' status.
How to stop create an order when transaction failed?

Answer (score 1):

Check this two event's

```
sales_order_place_after
sales_model_service_quote_submit_before
```

and check **save()** method.
Need to remove **save()** method from observer file.

**Ex.** `$this->orderRepository->save($orderInstance);`